# copying a static array to dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am defining a dynamic array in c++:

```
double *values;
int size = 5;
values = new (nothrow) double[size];
```

I know this works because it compiles, but I see some potential problems.

Say I want to assign values to this array:

```
double samples = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
values = samples; //runtime error: free or corruption
```

What exactly is happening to generate this error?

Comment: Maybe you mean `double samples[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};`

Comment: "I know this works because it compiles." Interesting approach.

Comment: You're not assigning values to `values`, you're just making it point to the first element of `samples`.

Comment: `values = samples;` actually does not cause any error. It makes the pointer `values` point to this array. However, there would be an error if you later tried `delete[] values;` because you would be trying to delete something that was not `new`'d.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::copy` to copy a static array to a dynamic array like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int main() {

   int *a = new int[5];
   int  b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   std::copy(b, b + 5, a);
   for(std::size_t i(0); i < 5; ++i) std::cout << a[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8db593e4e827300b)

Alternatively if you want the convenience of assignments instead of element-wise copying and provided that you know the size of the arrays in compile time and your compiler supports C++11 features, use `std::array`s like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {

   std::array<int, 5> a;
   std::array<int, 5> b {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
   a = b;
   for(auto i : a) std::cout << i << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e2a53c2198b602f)

However, it is recommend to prefer `std::vector` over the use of raw dynamic arrays like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> a(5);
   int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   std::copy(b, b + 5, a.begin());
   for(auto i : a) std::cout << i << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5571c206a83d6127)

Comment: You should not post any solution that involves new[].

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're assigning a static array to a pointer.

```
double *values;
double samples[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

They're two different data types as far as the compiler is concerned.

When you say:

```
values = new double[size];
```

You're creating a block of heap (dynamic) memory, and "values" holds the memory address of the first element in the array. To fill in the values from your static array, you need to assign each element individually like so:

```
values[0] = samples[0];
values[1] = samples[1];
// or better yet
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    values[i] = samples[i]
```

Comment: When you say `new double[size]`, you're creating memory leaks and buffer overruns.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `std::vector` which has an iterator constructor, this will solve the problem for you.

```
std::vector<double> values(std::begin(samples), std::end(samples));
```

This will ensure the heap memory is properly cleaned up, even in the case of exception, and employs the implementation's debugging machinery to help protect you from events like buffer overflow.